# Does SIR(Steric hindrance in resonance) affect inductive effect?

Tags: organic-chemistry, steric-effects

In 2,6-dichlorobenzoic acid, the $\ce{-COOH}$ group is pushed out of the plane restricting resonance.

[image]

**Question**: Does it mean the -I effect of chlorine atoms also cannot operate and reduce the charge on the deprotonated acid?

Comment: No, Inductive effect does operate because it is not dependent on orientation

Comment: Simple answer is no.

Comment: The inductive effect is not dependent on the orientation of the compound. Hence it will still work